# Is it possible to create and control threads manually with matlab?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing

I want to manage threads with Matlab manually.
Is it possible to create, Start and stop threads ?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if there is a pure matlab approach for this, but you can create a mex file and control threads there using C/C++. Also this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/calling-matlab-from-c-code-68913.html) will be useful

Comment: What do you want to do with these threads? You might mean: threads created from a MEX file to do arbitrary C++ stuff ; threads employed by MATLAB for intrinsic multithreaded support ; additional threads executing arbitrary MATLAB code. Each of those has a completely different answer...

Comment: Do you have the Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox ?  If you do the answer to your question is approximately *yes*.